# How to setup a local node for production?

Tags: full-node

I am planing to set up a nodeos local instance for RPC service for my company.

I am wondering...

1. Does [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/eosio/eos/) work?
2. How do I join the mainnet?
3. How much disk space will this node take, for now?
4. I need get_actions RPC, so I guess I need config filter_on_accounts in config.ini, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker image you're pointing to probably is built with the SYS CORE_SYMBOL. It's a way for Block.one to say: we're not running the mainnet.

You can use images we provide (at your own risk) here: https://hub.docker.com/r/eoscanada/eos/tags/

If you want `get_actions`, you'll want to enable the `history_api_plugin` (which serves the `/v1/history/get_actions` endpoint and friends). Then, you can add:

`filter-on = contractname   # for a given contract
filter-on = *              # to enable for all contracts`

in your `config.ini`.

There is also a tool we wrote to boot networks, local dev environments, etc.. it's in https://github.com/eoscanada/eos-bios .. it accumulated a bit of cruft for the launch of the mainnet, but we're cleaning out anything extraneous to make it a nice developer tool.

Regarding disk space: as of block #4415524 (which just passed a few seconds ago), disk space is 1.3GB for the "blocks/" logs (which live on disk), and 11 GB for the "state/" (with `filter-on = *` enabled and history api loaded), which lives in RAM (but also flushes to disk, through a mmap'd file).

Answer (score -1):

manual start testnet you can refer: https://github.com/EOSBIXIN/eostoolkit/tree/master/testnet